# How to generate sound from a waveform Data

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I have to make a project in ipad and my problem is that I have to play a sound generated from  a wave form/wave form data.

Can some one suggest me how to do that or any tutorial or reference for that.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ajay Sharma

Comment: Is the waveform data in memory or already in a file? How important is timing? Because there are several APIs you can use. AVAudioPlayer is the higher level API, or you can use AudioQueue services if timing is critical.

Comment: Can some one suggest some good tutorial or basic methodlogy to use these frameworks such as AudioQueue Services/AvAudioPlayer to use waveform data?

Answer (score 2):

Dave Dribin just gave a [presentation](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2010/05/02/ipad_dev_camp_slides/) on the use of Audio Queue Services and Audio Units, which I recommend you check out.  Additionally, he created two sample applications: one that [generates a 440 Hz tone](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2010/04/26/announcing_a440/) and another that [plays Nintendo .nsf files on the iPad](http://bitbucket.org/ddribin/chip-player).  Both of these are great starting points for learning these topics.